# Output for this program concerning void pointers

Tags: c, void-pointers

If the address of pointer ptr is 2000, then what will the output of following program?
[On 32 bit compiler.] (2)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  void *ptr;
  ++ptr;
  printf("%u",ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try it? did you run this code snippet? [**HINT**]what problems you have faced running this program?

Comment: how do i set the inital value of pointer to 2000. tried it on an online complier and it gives 1

Comment: Is `++ptr ` even a valid statement, with `ptr` being a `void`-pointer?

Comment: There are two specific things wrong, and the MSVC compiler points them out. A third was not pointed out. a) the size of `void*` is unknown, b) incorrect format specifier, and c) incrementing an uninitialised variable.

Comment: you dont. you cant. but this is not the motivation behind this question!

Comment: @WeatherVane: Out of curiosity: Which one missed MSVC?

Comment: @alk the unintialised c) which surprised me, MSVC usually picks that up.

Comment: But on the net, its wriiten that size of void pointer in 32 bit compiler is 4 bytes

Comment: @WeatherVane Maybe the compiler decided that c) does not happen at all, as incrementing a `void*` isn't possibly anyway.

Comment: @Nandz the size of the pointer does not matter. It is the size of `void` that is missing.

Comment: @Gerhardh correct. Change to `char*` and that warning is given instead.

Comment: @Nandz must be an old net you are looking at. A pointer is often 8 bytes size now, but it isn't relevant - the size of the object it is pointing to is what's relevant.

Comment: @WeatherVane: You seem to have caused confusion be commenting this "*a) the size of `void*` is unknown*" which should have read "*a) the size of `void` is unknown*" or "*a) the size of `*(void*)` is unknown*"

Comment: ... or even more explicit "*"*a) the size of what `void*` is pointing to is unknown*". I know you know, BTW.

Comment: @alk that's true, I should have said `void`. Because the compiler does not know the size of `void`, it does not know how much to add to the pointer's value (the address). If OP specifies `char*` it would add `1`. If OP specifies `double*` it would add 8,  `sizeof (double)`.

Answer (score 1):

> *what will the output of following program?*

From the C Standard's perspective the output is not defined, as the program runs into undefined behaviour, even before anything would have been printed, for several reasons:

1. The statement `++ptr` tries to increment `ptr` by an unknown number. Incrementing a pointer tries to add the number of bytes the type uses the pointer is pointing to. A `void`-pointer points to nothing, and nothing has no size, not even `0`.

   Let `T` be any type in the example below:

   ```
   T * p = ...; /* Define p and initialise it to any address. */
   ```

   Then

   ```
   ++p;
   ```

   is equivalent to:

   ```
   p = (T*)((char*)p + sizeof *p);
   ```

   Try the above with `T` being replaced by `void`.

   Note: GCC, as an extension to the C Standard treats `void`-pointers like `char`-pointers.
2. `ptr` is (tried to being, see 1.) applied an arithmetic operation when being
   uninitialised.
3. The `u` conversion specifier is to print out an `unsigned int`, the code passes a pointer. To print a pointer's value use the `p` conversion specifier.